# How to get the parameter type of the class method with macro?

Tags: macros, haxe

How to get the parameter type of the class method with macro?

```
class A{
 public function new(){
  //this how get method out arg[0] Type with macro?
  var arg0IsInt:Bool=arg0IsInt(out);
 }
 public function out(a:Int){ return true; }

 macro public function arg0IsInt(e:Expr):Bool{
 } 

}
```

I'm going to call a method that has a parameter for a type when I construct a letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `out` to the expression macro and then use [`Context.typeof()`](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Context.html?#typeof) on it. The result will be a [function type](https://haxe.org/manual/types-function.html) ([`TFun`](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Type.html#TFun)) whose first argument you can inspect using [pattern matching](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching-introduction.html).

Here's a working example:

```
import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;

class Main {
    static function main() {
        new Main();
    }

    public function new() {
        trace(arg0IsInt(out)); // true
        trace(arg0IsInt(out2)); // false
    }

    public function out(a:Int) {}

    public function out2(a:Float) {}

    macro static function arg0IsInt(func:Expr):Expr {
        return switch Context.typeof(func) {
            case TFun(args, _):
                switch args[0].t {
                    case TAbstract(_.get() => t, _) if (t.name == "Int" && t.pack.length == 0):
                        macro true;
                    case _:
                        macro false;
                }
            case _:
                throw 'argument should be a function';
        }
    }
}
```

`Int` is a an `abstract`, and to make sure it's not just some random abstract that happens to be named `Int` in some other package, we check that it's in the toplevel package (`pack.length == 0`).

Answer (score 2):

In fact you can go very far with pattern matching:

```
import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;

class Test {
    static function main() {
        new Test();
    }

    public function new() {
        trace(arg0IsInt(out)); // true
        trace(arg0IsInt(out2)); // false
    }

    public function out(a:Int) {}

    public function out2(a:Float) {}

    macro static function arg0IsInt(func:Expr):Expr {
        return switch Context.typeof(func) {
            case TFun(_[0] => {t: TAbstract(_.get() => {name: 'Int', pack: []}, _)}, _): macro true;
            case TFun(_): macro false;
            case _: throw 'argument should be a function';
        }
    }
}
```